# getc() not working outside of main function

Tags: c, stdio

I wrote a small program which uses an XTEA cipher algorithm to encipher or decipher a given textfile.
It all worked fine until I started to tidy up my program.

Here's the code that used to work:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char* filename = malloc(20*sizeof(uint8_t));
    uint32_t* argBuf = malloc(2*sizeof(uint32_t)); /* used to buffer (de)cypher strings */
    uint32_t* keyBuf = malloc(4*sizeof(uint32_t));      /* used to store the cypher key */
    int character, i, opt, filelen;
    FILE *finp, *fdec, *fenc;
    i = 0;
    /* get plaintext input file */
    printf("Please enter the following filenames. They\r\n");
    printf("shall be no longer than 100 characters.\r\n");
    printf("Input filename: \r\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(filename);
    fflush(stdin);
    finp = fopen(filename, "r"); 
    if (finp == NULL){
        printf("Error! Input file not found!\r\n");
        return;
    }
.
. /* opening the other file(s) and other stuff not related to problem */
.

    /* iterate over file */ 
    while ((character = getc(finp)) != EOF){
        i++;
        *(((uint8_t*)argBuf) + i) = (uint8_t) character;
        if (++i == 8){
            /* encode */
            printf("\r\nnon ciphered text: ");
            printText((uint64_t*)argBuf);
            printf("\r\nciphered text: ");
            encipher(NUM_CYCLES, argBuf, keyBuf);
            storeCipherText((uint64_t*)argBuf, fenc);
            printText((uint64_t*)argBuf);
            i = 0;
            argBuf[0] = 0;
            argBuf[1] = 0;
        }
    }
```

}

Output (just proving that the file could be read):

```
***************************************************
*              Cipher programm using XTEA         *
***************************************************

Please enter the following filenames. They
shall be no longer than 20 characters.
Input filename:
t.txt
Cipher text output file: 
aaaa
Deciphered text output file: 
t2.txt

non ciphered text: Hall
ciphered text: *j|+A
.
.
.
```

Now I wrote a helper function which handles file opening and reading. It is contained in a function called "HandleEncipher":

```
void HandleEncipher(void){
char* filename = malloc(20*sizeof(uint8_t));
uint32_t* argBuf = malloc(2*sizeof(uint32_t)); /* used to buffer (de)cypher strings */
uint32_t* keyBuf = malloc(4*sizeof(uint32_t));     /* used to store the cypher key */
int character, i;
FILE *finp, *foutp;

/* get plaintext input file */
printf("Please enter the following filenames. They\r\n");
printf("shall be no longer than 100 characters.\r\n");
printf("Input filename: \r\n");
fflush(stdin);
gets(filename);
fflush(stdin);
finp = fopen(filename, "r"); 
if (finp == NULL){
    printf("Error! Input file not found!\r\n");
    return;
}

/* get cipher text output file */
printf("Cipher text output file: \r\n");
gets(filename);
foutp = fopen(filename, "wb");                 /* create or clear file */
if (foutp == NULL){
    printf("Error! Can't write to output file!\r\n");
    return;
}

StoreCipherKey(keyBuf);

argBuf[0] = 0;                          /* initialize buffer and index */
argBuf[1] = 0;
i = 0;

printf("start iterating");
/* iterate over file */ 
while ((character = fgetc(finp)) != EOF){
    i++;
    printf("character#: %i", i);
    *(((uint8_t*)argBuf) + i) = (uint8_t) character;
    if (++i == 8){
        /* encode */
        printf("\r\nnon ciphered text: ");
        printText((uint64_t*)argBuf);
        printf("\r\nciphered text: ");
        printText((uint64_t*)argBuf);
        storeCipherText((uint64_t*)argBuf, foutp);
        i = 0;
        argBuf[0] = 0;
        argBuf[1] = 0;
    }
}
}
```

Another funny detail is that if I debug the code in Visual Studio Code, my finp variable equals NULL if using the "HandleEncipher" function.

I'm quite confused since the outsourced code is practically a copy of the code that ran fine in main. I have no idea of what could be going wrong (aside from poor boundary checking for the input string). But I used the exact same filenames for the second version as in the first version and if I use filename for a non-existent file, my program reacts accordingly.

Anybody having an idea on what's going on here?

Comment: If you observed `finp` being null, I suggest undefined behavior in `StoreCipherKey`.

Comment: Oh, that's a very good point! I might be doing some dumb stuff in there. Let me check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StoreCipherKey Function:

```
void StoreCipherKey(uint32_t keyBuffer[4]){
    uint8_t i;
    /* fill key into buffer */
    for (i = 0; i < KEYSIZE/(2*sizeof(*keyBuffer)); i++){
        if (i < KEYSIZE/(sizeof(*keyBuffer)*2)){
            keyBuffer[i] = (uint32_t) TEST_KEY_LOWER >> (i*32);
        } else {
            keyBuffer[i-KEYSIZE/(sizeof(*keyBuffer)*2)]  = (uint32_t) TEST_KEY_UPPER >> ((i - 2*sizeof(*keyBuffer))*32);
        }
    } 
}
```

Here I overran the keyBuffer. This lead to undefined behavior. Yes, in my current timezone it is too late to be programming.

Thanks @Joshua for hinting at the problem.

Comment: Note: KEYSIZE is in bits and sizeof works with Bytes as unit. So that's where I made my mistake.